# Destroy all models in Backbone collection (persisted in local storage)

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-local-storage

How do I delete all models in my collection (persisted in local storage)?

The models are fetched from local storage - I want the models to be destroyed both at the client and also in local storage.

```
// Model + Collection
App.Models.Task = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        text: 'N/A'
    }
});

App.Collections.Tasks = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: App.Models.Task,
    localStorage: new Backbone.LocalStorage("task")
});


// Create collection and fetch tasks 
var tasks = new App.Collections.Tasks();
tasks.fetch(); // collection is now populated with 4 tasks


// Delete all models (both at client and local storage)
tasks.each(function(model) {
   model.destroy();
})
```

From running this, I destroy only some of the models - this error occurs and prevents the rest from being destroyed:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'destroy' of undefined
```

Any help on this is greatly appreciated!

Comment: if it a complete code problem is in async type of fetch. to iterate over collection you have to wait until fetch is done.

Comment: The iteration is initiated when clicking a button - this is done when the data has been fetched, so I don't think this is the issue

Comment: could u please attach `console.log(model)` output inside a loop ?

Comment: The console.log outputs the models without any problem - please see the solution below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution:

```
_.invoke(tasks.toArray(), 'destroy');
```

Apparently, using the .each to destroy models is a bad practice, since the internal iteration gets messed up by the continual deletion of models.

Comment: can you elaborate by how the internal iterations gets mess up by the deletion of models?

Comment: The iteration does not take account for the element that is suddenly missing. Therefore the method above works, or using a for-loop that runs in reverse